# IIS 7.5 only allows one user to view web site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a web site developed in VS2010 Framework 4.0 published to a Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5
(As a bit of side info - I have a copy of the same site (apart, obviously, from the Framework) developed in VS2005 Framework 2.0 published on a Windows 2003 server that works perfectly.)

When I publish the Framework 4.0 site to the Windows 2008 server, it only works for the first person that tries to access the site. E.g. I publish it to the server, and then access the site from my PC using IE. Someone at the desk next to me tries to access the site and nothing happens - the browser progress bar just chuggs along going nowhere - no errors, no errors on the server, nothing. If I log out and the person at the desk next to me accesses the site - it works fine. If I then try to access it - the browser just hangs and goes nowhere. So, only one person is allowed to use this web site! (It's on an intranet).
If, while someone is using the site, I go into IIS and browse the site - it connects perfectly.

The site has a global.asax which calls a stored procedure to do some log ins and sets 5 session variables.

Any ideas please. It's driving me nuts and has caused me to go back to VS2005 and Framework 2.0

** Added code from comment below**

```
string CurrUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString().Replace("\\"‌​, "/"); 
CPDataAccess.DataAccess da = new CPDataAccess.DataAccess(); 
System.Data.DataView dvGetUserCurrWP; 
dvGetUserCurrWP = da.GetUserCurrWP(CurrUser); 
int somerows = dvGetUserCurrWP.Count;
```

Comment: There could be any number of code bottlenecks that cause this.  Have you looked in the event log?  Have you checked your code for non-terminating loops or non-terminating recursive calls?  There's really not enough info here to give you an answer...

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for this question to be answered. We don't know what is your code, what's this code doing. If the project is not very large, try to remove parts of the code until it works to figure out where the error is.

Comment: My guess is that this is an issue with your code, not IIS. If IIS were only allowing 1 visitor, the page wouldn't event show loading progress.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have dissected the code to the nth degree. The exact same code in global.asax and default.aspx works perfectly on the Windows 2003 server. The code is literally the same - I copied over all the pages from the new dev box (VS2010 - Framework 4.) to my old dev box (VS2005 - Framework 2) this morning - and published to the Windows 2003 server that runs various sites for us.

Comment: I agree with the other comments so far, the assumption that IIS is the problem is absurd.  Regardless that the code is the same, the problem is your code or your config.

Comment: I have stripped things down - excluded all pages except default.aspx and just to test if this is a session thing - I have put a linkbutton on the page that, on postback, clears and abandons the session. I have 3 browsers open on different PCs and have been going from one to another seeing what happens with various web.config changes. On all the machines, when I do get the site to show up, I always have to click the Log Out button twice - the first click it just hangs. Second click, logs out immediately.

Comment: <appSettings>
  <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
  <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
  <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>

  <!--******************* LIVE ******************-->
  <add key="ConnectionString" value="server=*********;Trusted_Connection=YES;database=*************;Integrated Security=true;Connect Timeout=0"/>
  <add key="EmailAttachmentsPath" value="C:\CPEmailAttachments\"/>
 </appSettings>

Comment: Okay, sorry, no point in that - can you format code on here?

Comment: Do you have any logging around Application_Start, Application_End, Application_Error in Global.asax? If so, are those methods getting called? Also, what session state mode are you using?

Comment: No I don't have any logging there. Session state is inproc.

Comment: The big question here is: What are you doing in your global.asax?  Post that code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection and bandwidth limits under the performance tab.

**EDIT**

Since the DataView inherits from MarshallByValueComponent, which implements IDisposable, try adding a using statement for your datacall:

```
using (System.Data.Dataview dvGetUserCurrWP = da.GetUserCurrWP(CurrUser))
{
    int somerows = dvGetUserCurrWP.Count;
    if (somerows)
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I have stripped the thing down to the bare bones now. Nothing in global.asax and nothing on default.aspx apart from retrieving the user's identity from Windows.Identity and displaying it on the screen.
This works fine and I can open multiple browsers on different machines and they all work.
Introduce the code into Session_Start in global.asax that gets the User's details from the database and set a few session variables - and that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: There is no limits on bandwidth and connection timeout is set to 120

Comment: I understand your problem now, but you will have to post some code in order for me to help.

Comment: is there a way of formatting code on here?

Here is the code in global.asax that seems to cause the problem:

string CurrUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString().Replace("\\", "/");

        CPDataAccess.DataAccess da = new CPDataAccess.DataAccess();
        System.Data.DataView dvGetUserCurrWP;
        dvGetUserCurrWP = da.GetUserCurrWP(CurrUser);
        int somerows = dvGetUserCurrWP.Count;

Comment: else
        {
            Session["WPID"] = 0;
            Session["UserID"] = 0;
            Session["UserName"] = "";
            Session["GroupID"] = 0;
            Session["GroupName"] = "";
        }

Comment: Edit your question and include the code. That way it will be easier for other people to answer too.

Comment: Aaaarghhh - how can post code on here?

string CurrUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString().Replace("\\", "/");

CPDataAccess.DataAccess da = new CPDataAccess.DataAccess();
System.Data.DataView dvGetUserCurrWP;
dvGetUserCurrWP = da.GetUserCurrWP(CurrUser);
int somerows = dvGetUserCurrWP.Count;

Comment: I don't get this - I'm putting soft returns between the lines of code but they still wrap ...

if (somerows > 0)
{
 Session["WPID"] = dvGetUserCurrWP[0]["WorkProgramID"];
Session["UserID"] = dvGetUserCurrWP[0]["UserID"];
Session["UserName"] = dvGetUserCurrWP[0]["Fullname"];
Session["GroupID"] = dvGetUserCurrWP[0]["GroupID"];
Session["GroupName"] = dvGetUserCurrWP[0]["GroupName"];
}

Comment: else
{
Session["WPID"] = 0;
Session["UserID"] = 0;
Session["UserName"] = "";
Session["GroupID"] = 0;
Session["GroupName"] = "";
}

Comment: Okay, that's the pretty unreadable code that runs in Session_Start.

It accesses a data access class, connects to the database and retrieves data about the user into a dataview. This all works okay, has been working for years in other apps. But, in this app, on a server running IIS 7.5 - as soon as I set some sessions - it only allows one (or two if I'm lucky) users to access the site.

Comment: So there's only one or two users that can ACCESS to site at one time? What happens when users cannot access the site?

Comment: The browser just hangs - the progress bar in the browser just goes on forever.

Comment: Just did it again - commented out the code in Session_Start that sets the session variables - published - all works fine. Put it back in - only one (or sometimes two) people can access the site.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion - I tried that and it still does not work. I have moved the log in code out of global.asax and into default.aspx - changed from a DataView to a SqlDataReader - used a 'Using' statement and explicitly disposed of the SqlDataReader.
Still does not work.

Comment: Okay, fixed it I think. I changed 'Connect Timeout=0' in the connection string in web.config to 'Connect Timeout=15' and, who knows why, it seems to work.

Comment: Better yet, just remove the Connect Timeout value altogether. It's a documented issue, as noted here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/331882/connect-timeout-0-connection-pool-timeout

Comment: Thanks for that link James - to be honest I thought I was going nuts and half imagining the whole thing. Two days of trial and error and checking and re-checking code that has been working for years ... and I searched high and low on the web and found nothing on it. I only set Connect Timeout=15 in desperation as had literally run out of things to try.